# Latex overleaf error that I can't seem to solve

Tags: overleaf, compilation-error

I'm working on my master's thesis, in which in want to use Overleaf Latex. I have some small experience in using Overleaf Latex, so I started by creating a new project and used a preamble one of my old colleagues had created for a prior project. For some reason I'm getting an error that I can't figure out how to solve.

The error is this:

```
Package nameref Warning: The definition of \label has changed! Check your packages! 
Replacing it with the kernel definition on input line 145.
```

And this error:

```
<*> preamble_ida.tex
                    
*** (job aborted, no legal \end found)

 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 24208 strings out of 475237
 427272 string characters out of 5764570
 1917244 words of memory out of 5000000
 45183 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 559543 words of font info for 40 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1143 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 79i,1n,117p,388b,265s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I guess it has something to do with the packages in the preamble.tex file? but i have no idea. I hoped someone with more experience could help me solve this so i can start my actual work.

My preamble file looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn,oneside,openright]{memoir}    % Openright aabner kapitler paa hoejresider (openany = vilkaarlig/begge

%%%% PAKKER %%%%

\usepackage{rotating}
% ¤¤ Oversaettelse og tegnsaetning ¤¤ %
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                 % Input-indkodning af tegnsaet, dvs. input fra keyboard, tegnoversigt eller andet (UTF8 = Unicode)
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                    % Output-indkodning af tegnsaet, dvs. printede fonte og tegn (T1 = Type 1 font med support for de fleste europaeiske sprog)
\usepackage[danish]{babel}                  % Sproglig fremstilling af elementer (figur vs. figure, litteratur vs. bibliography osv.)
\usepackage{ragged2e,anyfontsize}           % Justering af elementer
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{ulem}

%\usepackage{lmodern}

%\usepackage{minted}

% ¤¤ Figurer og tabeller (floats) ¤¤ %
\usepackage{graphicx}                       % Inkludering af eksterne billeder (JPG, PNG, PDF)
\usepackage{multirow}                       % Fletning af raekker og kolonner (\multicolumn og \multirow)
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{colortbl}                       % Farver i tabeller (fx \columncolor, \rowcolor og \cellcolor)
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}             % Definer farver med \definecolor. Se mere: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Colors
\usepackage{flafter}                        % Soerger for, at floats ikke optraeder i teksten foer deres reference
\usepackage{float}                          % Muliggoer eksakt placering af floats, fx \begin{figure}[H]
\let\newfloat\relax                         % Justering mellem float-pakken og memoir
%\usepackage{eso-pic}                       % Tilfoej billedekommandoer paa hver side
%\usepackage{wrapfig}                       % Indsaettelse af figurer omsvoebt af tekst 
%\usepackage{multicol}                      % Muliggoer tekst i spalter
%\usepackage{rotating}                      % Rotation af tekst med \begin{sideways}...\end{sideways}

% ¤¤ Matematik mm. ¤¤
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,stmaryrd}       % Avancerede matematik-udvidelser
\usepackage{mathtools}                      % Andre matematik- og tegnudvidelser
\usepackage{textcomp}                       % Symbol-udvidelser (fx promille-tegn med \textperthousand)
\usepackage{siunitx}                        % Flot og konsistent praesentation af tal og enheder med \si{enhed} og \SI{tal}{enhed}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker = {,}}       % Opsaetning af \SI og decimalseparator
%\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}             % Kemi-pakke til flot og let notation af formler, fx \ce{Fe2O3}
%\usepackage{rsphrase}                      % Kemi-pakke til RS-saetninger, fx \rsphrase{R1}

% ¤¤ Referencer og kilder ¤¤ %
\usepackage[danish]{varioref}               % Muliggoer bl.a. krydshenvisninger med sidetal (\vref)
\usepackage{natbib}                         % Udvidelse med naturvidenskabelige citationsmodeller, herunder Harvard-modellen
%\usepackage{xr}                            % Referencer til eksternt dokument med \externaldocument{<NAVN>}
%\usepackage{glossaries}                    % Terminologi- eller symbolliste (se mere i Lars Madsens Latex-bog)
% ¤¤ Misc. ¤¤ %
\usepackage{listings}                       % Placer kildekode i dokumentet med \begin{lstlisting}...\end{lstlisting}\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lmodern}
%\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{lipsum}                         % Dummy tekst med fx \lipsum[2]
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}          % Muliggoer enkelt konfiguration af lister (se \setlist nedenfor)
\usepackage{pdfpages}                       % Goer det muligt at inkludere pdf-dokumenter med kommandoen \includepdf[pages={x-y}]{fil.pdf}  
\pdfoptionpdfminorversion=6                 % Muliggoer inkludering af pdf-dokumenter af version 1.6 og hoejere
\pretolerance=2500                          % Justering af afstand mellem ord (hoejt tal, mindre orddeling og mere luft mellem ord)

% Kommentarer og rettelser med \fxnote. Med 'final' i stedet for 'draft' udloeser hver note en error i den faerdige rapport.
\usepackage[footnote,draft,danish,silent,nomargin]{fixme}       


%%%% BRUGERDEFINEREDE INDSTILLINGER %%%%

% ¤¤ Marginer ¤¤ %
\setlrmarginsandblock{2.5cm}{2.5cm}{*}      % \setlrmarginsandblock{Indbinding}{Kant}{Ratio}
\setulmarginsandblock{2.5cm}{3.0cm}{*}      % \setulmarginsandblock{Top}{Bund}{Ratio}
\checkandfixthelayout                       % Oversaetter vaerdier til brug for andre pakker

%   ¤¤ Afsnitsformatering ¤¤ %
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}                 % Stoerrelse af indryk
\setlength{\parskip}{3mm}                   % Afstand mellem afsnit ved brug af double Enter
\linespread{1,1}                            % Linjeafstand

% ¤¤ Litteraturlisten ¤¤ %
\bibpunct[,]{[}{]}{;}{a}{,}{,}              % Definerer parametre ved Harvard-henvisning (bl.a. parantestype og seperatortegn)
\bibliographystyle{bibtex/harvard}          % Udseende af litteraturlisten (Harvard-metoden - skift til fx 'plain' for tal)

% ¤¤ Dybde af overskrifter ¤¤ %
\setsecnumdepth{subsection}                 % Dybden af nummerede overkrifter (part/chapter/section/subsection)
\settocdepth{subsection}                    % Dybden af overskrifter vist i indholdsfortegnelsen

% ¤¤ Lister ¤¤ %
\setlist{
  topsep=0pt,                               % Vertikal afstand mellem tekst og listen
  itemsep=-1ex,                             % Vertikal afstand mellem items
} 

% ¤¤ Visuelle referencer ¤¤ %
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}           % Danner klikbare referencer (hyperlinks) i dokumentet
\hypersetup{colorlinks = true,              % Opsaetning af farvede hyperlinks (interne links, citeringer og URL)
    linkcolor = black,
    citecolor = black,
    urlcolor = black
}

% ¤¤ Opsaetning af figur- og tabeltekst ¤¤ %
\captionnamefont{\small\bfseries\itshape}   % Opsaetning af tekstdelen ('Figur' eller 'Tabel')
\captiontitlefont{\small}                   % Opsaetning af nummerering
\captiondelim{. }                           % Seperator mellem nummerering og figurtekst
\captionstyle{\centering}                   % Justering/placering af figurteksten (centreret = \centering, venstrejusteret = \raggedright)
\captionwidth{\linewidth}                   % Bredden af figurteksten
\hangcaption                                % Venstrejusterer fler-linjers figurtekst under hinanden
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{0pt}          % Afstand under figurteksten
\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup[table]{skip=10pt}

% ¤¤ Opsaetning af listings ¤¤ %
\definecolor{commentGreen}{RGB}{34,139,24}
\definecolor{stringPurple}{RGB}{208,76,239}

\lstset{language=Matlab,                    % Sprog
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize,        % Opsaetning af teksten
    keywords={for,if,while,else,elseif,     % Noegleord at fremhaeve
              end,break,return,case,
              switch,function},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},              % Opsaetning af noegleord
    commentstyle=\color{commentGreen},      % Opsaetning af kommentarer
    stringstyle=\color{stringPurple},       % Opsaetning af strenge
    showstringspaces=false,                 % Mellemrum i strenge enten vist eller blanke
    numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny,        % Linjenumre
    extendedchars=true,                     % Tillader specielle karakterer
    columns=flexible,                       % Kolonnejustering
    breaklines, breakatwhitespace=true,     % Bryd lange linjer
}

%% DETTE HAR VI SELV INDSAT %%
\definecolor{bluekeywords}{rgb}{0,0,1}
\definecolor{lightgray}{rgb}{0.95, 0.95, 0.95}
\definecolor{greencomments}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\definecolor{redstrings}{rgb}{0.64,0.08,0.08}
\definecolor{xmlcomments}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{types}{rgb}{0.17,0.57,0.68}

\lstset{language=[Sharp]C,
captionpos=b,
%numbers=left, %Nummerierung
%numberstyle=\tiny, % kleine Zeilennummern
frame=l, % Oberhalb und unterhalb des Listings ist eine Linie
showspaces=false,
showtabs=false,
breaklines=true,
showstringspaces=false,
breakatwhitespace=true,
escapeinside={(*@}{@*)},
commentstyle=\color{greencomments},
morekeywords={partial, var, value, get, set},
keywordstyle=\color{bluekeywords},
stringstyle=\color{redstrings},
basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
   backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray}
}

% ¤¤ Navngivning ¤¤ %
\addto\captionsdanish{
    \renewcommand\contentsname{Indholdsfortegnelse}         % Skriver 'Indholdsfortegnelse' i stedet for 'Indhold'
    \renewcommand\appendixname{Appendiks}                   % Skriver 'Appendiks' i stedet for 'Appendix'
    \renewcommand\appendixpagename{Appendiks}
    \renewcommand\appendixtocname{Appendiks}
    \renewcommand\cftchaptername{\chaptername~}             % Skriver 'Kapitel' foran kapitlerne i indholdsfortegnelsen
    \renewcommand\cftappendixname{\appendixname~}           % Skriver 'Appendiks' foran appendiks i indholdsfortegnelsen
}

% ¤¤ Kapiteludssende ¤¤ %
\definecolor{numbercolor}{gray}{0.7}        % Definerer en farve til brug til kapiteludseende
\newif\ifchapternonum

\makechapterstyle{jenor}{                   % Definerer kapiteludseende frem til ...
  \renewcommand\beforechapskip{0pt}
  \renewcommand\printchaptername{}
  \renewcommand\printchapternum{}
  \renewcommand\printchapternonum{\chapternonumtrue}
  \renewcommand\chaptitlefont{\fontfamily{pbk}\fontseries{db}\fontshape{n}\fontsize{25}{35}\selectfont\raggedleft}
  \renewcommand\chapnumfont{\fontfamily{pbk}\fontseries{m}\fontshape{n}\fontsize{1in}{0in}\selectfont\color{numbercolor}}
  \renewcommand\printchaptertitle[1]{%
    \noindent
    \ifchapternonum
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X}
    {\let\\\newline\chaptitlefont ##1\par} 
    \end{tabularx}
    \par\vskip-2.5mm\hrule
    \else
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xl}
    {\parbox[b]{\linewidth}{\chaptitlefont ##1}} & \raisebox{-15pt}{\chapnumfont \thechapter}
    \end{tabularx}
    \par\vskip2mm\hrule
    \fi
  }
}                                           % ... her

\chapterstyle{jenor}                        % Valg af kapiteludseende - Google 'memoir chapter styles' for alternativer

% ¤¤ Sidehoved/sidefod ¤¤ %

\makepagestyle{Uni}                         % Definerer sidehoved og sidefod udseende frem til ...
\makepsmarks{Uni}{%
    \createmark{chapter}{left}{shownumber}{}{. \ }
    \createmark{section}{right}{shownumber}{}{. \ }
    \createplainmark{toc}{both}{\contentsname}
    \createplainmark{lof}{both}{\listfigurename}
    \createplainmark{lot}{both}{\listtablename}
    \createplainmark{bib}{both}{\bibname}
    \createplainmark{index}{both}{\indexname}
    \createplainmark{glossary}{both}{\glossaryname}
}
\nouppercaseheads                                           % Ingen Caps oenskes

\makeevenhead{Uni}{Group }{}{\leftmark}             % Lige siders sidehoved (\makeevenhead{Navn}{Venstre}{Center}{Hoejre})
\makeoddhead{Uni}{\rightmark}{}{Aalborg University}         % Ulige siders sidehoved (\makeoddhead{Navn}{Venstre}{Center}{Hoejre})
\makeevenfoot{Uni}{\thepage}{}{}                            % Lige siders sidefod (\makeevenfoot{Navn}{Venstre}{Center}{Hoejre})
\makeoddfoot{Uni}{}{}{\thepage}                             % Ulige siders sidefod (\makeoddfoot{Navn}{Venstre}{Center}{Hoejre})
\makeheadrule{Uni}{\textwidth}{0.5pt}                       % Tilfoejer en streg under sidehovedets indhold
\makefootrule{Uni}{\textwidth}{0.5pt}{1mm}                  % Tilfoejer en streg under sidefodens indhold

\copypagestyle{Unichap}{Uni}                                % Der dannes en ny style til kapitelsider
\makeoddhead{Unichap}{}{}{}                                 % Sidehoved defineres som blank på kapitelsider
\makeevenhead{Unichap}{}{}{}
\makeheadrule{Unichap}{\textwidth}{0pt}
\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{Unichap}                           % Den ny style vaelges til at gaelde for chapters
                                                            % ... her
\pagestyle{Uni}                                             % Valg af sidehoved og sidefod (benyt 'plain' for ingen sidehoved/fod)


%%%% EGNE KOMMANDOER %%%%

% ¤¤ Billede hack ¤¤ %                                      % Indsaet figurer nemt med \figur{Stoerrelse}{Fil}{Figurtekst}{Label}
\newcommand{\figur}[4]{
        \begin{figure}[H] \centering
            \includegraphics[width=#1\textwidth]{billeder/#2}
            \caption{#3}
            \label{#4}
        \end{figure} 
}

% ¤¤ Specielle tegn ¤¤ %
\newcommand{\dec}{^{\circ}}                                 % '\dec' returnerer et gradtegn (husk $$ udenfor aligns)
\newcommand{\decC}{^{\circ}\text{C}}                        % '\decC' returnerer et gradtegn + 'C' (husk $$ udenfor aligns)
\newcommand{\m}{\cdot}                                      % '\m' returnerer et gangetegn

%%%% ORDDELING %%%%
\hyphenation{In-te-res-se e-le-ment}
```

Comment: Please make a small, but compilable test document which reproduces your problem.

Comment: the nameref warning is only a warning not an error, the error probably means that you are trying to compile your preamble instead of your document.

Comment: this is not really a reasonable example but the error messag is quite clear your file has no `\end{document}` so the job does not end, you could remove every line except the first and get the same error.

Comment: the nameref warning is from the memoir class which is a bit outdated on overleaf. The warning is harmless and it will be gone once overleaf updates to texlive 2024.

Comment: Mostly but not entirely unrelated: the preamble seems rather complex with all the packages, settings and redefinitions. This could cause all kinds of issues later on, and you most likely don't actually need most of it to write your thesis. So I would advise to remove all packages of which you currently cannot point out in your document where you are using them, and the same for the redefinitions. If at a later point you are missing something then you can always add it back. This will make your document easier to debug and faster to compile without losing much functionality (if any).

Comment: Note that Overleaf is just your editor. It has nothing to do with the error. (It is relevant to the warning only because it tells us your version of TeX Live is slightly outdated. But, even so, the warning is no related to Overleaf *per se*.) `I ... used a preamble one of my old colleagues had created for a prior project`: don't. I know this seems like a good idea right now but, really, it isn't.

Comment: Suggestion: Do not use foreign preambles.Start with `\documentclass{memoir} \begin{document} foo \end{document}` and then only add whatever in the preamble only if it is really necessary  (e.g.,  the  `graphicx` package only if you include an image) and you are sure of what is for, and then always check that the document is still compilable. This way you will know what are you doing really, and your code will be simpler, faster and safer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have simplified your example to

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn,oneside,openright]{memoir}
```

(You should probably simplify your real document in a similar way)

Running that with

```
pdflatex --interaction=batchmode file
```

produces a log file

```
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-03-14>
)
! Emergency stop.
<*> file
         
*** (job aborted, no legal \end found)

 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 14 strings out of 474104
 336 string characters out of 5743473
 1925493 words of memory out of 5000000
 22486 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 558069 words of font info for 36 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 12i,0n,13p,68b,8s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

as there is no `\end{document}` (and no document content at all).

You can fix it by changing the document to

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn,oneside,openright]{memoir}
\begin{document}
x
\end{document}
```

So that the document finishes and a pdf is produced.

It may be that you have another document looking like

```
\input{preamble_ida.tex}
\begin{document}
x
\end{document}
```

In which case you should run latex on *that* document but I would not split the file in such a way. It is better to have the `\documentclass` line in your main document file.

Comment: So i do have the begin and end in my main document, it still produces the same error.\input{preamble_ida.tex}           % 
\begin{document}
\end{documen

Comment: it seems the main document was missing: \documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn,oneside,openright]{memoir}

It is now working and producing the PDF. Thank you very much for the reply David!